# how to get the outbound HTTP request of a certain exe application?

Tags: java, http, monitoring

let's say i have an ".EXE application" and run it on my windows, 
so, the second thing i want is to capture the outbound HTTP requested by the

".EXE application". is there any java library i could use to capture outbound HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying calling tcpdump from your program by following this tutorial.

http://www.ehow.com/how_10065937_run-tcpdump-java.html

:D

lol @ an e-how tutorial on how to already do this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i will look into this. but what i really want is like a fiddler that captures the readable outbound http request (not raw information).

Comment: You could capture with this program then open the capture file in *Wireshark* and find all the HTTP traffic color coded in a GUI. I had to Google *Fiddler*. This seems like a protocol analyser for Windows. Tcpdump I don't think works for Windows, but Wireshark does. You maybe able to call a command line version of Wireshark in the same way as you would do in the e-how tcpdump example. You could then use some type of regex to filter for HTTP traffic as java has a serious regex engine. :D

Comment: I've tried both tshark and tcpdump running on commandline, and i was able to get the the outbound http request. so the last thing I need to do is to apply some filtering on the output file and parse it using java to extract downloadable links. thanks for your help dude @user_loser

Comment: @prix Cool! You are welcome. :D Glad to help. RegEx can filter lots of stuff. It does have a huge learning curve to scale though as it is its own language, but lots of programming languages use it. You could try using `grep` to filter for `HTTP` in a capture file. Thanks for the positive feedback. I am glad it worked out.